# What is a Tropical Forcing and is it related to Climate Forcing?

Tags: meteorology

I see the term Tropical Forcing used in weather synopses but have been unable to find a concise definition of the term. Also, is "Tropical Forcing" a different concept than "Climate Forcing"?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Modes of tropical forcing observed during Autumn will continue. In the aggregate, they will support from the southeast US. This would force the storm track over or northwest of the area. With lower troughing over the Great Lakes with potential for well defined episodes of ridging building confidence, modeling indicates this tendency decreasing as convection migrates east of 160 E, which could mitigate the amplitude of the southeast US ridge or even reinforce support for troughing if it makes sufficient eastward progress.

Comment: tried to find that text on Google, but failed... it would be best to put it in the question :)  That way those who aren't as familiar with it, or not sure the context they've heard it in, can see it :)

Comment: It was buried in a NOAA page that is likely not being indexed, but there are numerous examples found with a google search.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the context. But I have added my intuitive explanation below. My general instinct is that whenever something is labeled as a forcing, the person writing it is as a black box. So "tropical forcing" likely means the area of interest is extratropical. When someone writes "climate forcing" the subject is something that is not climate (such as biology).

The tropics have dynamics and features that are different from the other parts of the climate (midlatitudes, upper latitudes). In the tropics, a good amount of the circulation is driven by condensation. In the tropics, the amount of sunlight that is received does not vary as much as in the midlatitudes. The tropics can generate features, such as tropical cyclones, the Intertropical convergence zone, or El Nino/La Nina that heavily influences the midlatitudes.

Climate forcing, on the other hand, is a general term that describes the mechanics of the atmosphere at large. These include heat transport by ocean gyres, aerosols, and greenhouse gas forcing. Now one can make the argument that this distinction between tropics and extratropics is semantic, which is fair. But it follows in the methodological reductionism of science to break the climate system by geography.